# /proc/ioports is empty in beagleboard

Tags: drivers, arm, proc, beagleboard

I am trying to find the port addresses in Ubuntu in beaglebone black. When I try to open `/proc/ioports` file, it shows the file is empty.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How do you try to open the file?

Comment: i tried to open that file by becoming a root user.

Comment: Becoming a root user doesn't open the file. What did you do to open the file after becoming root?

Comment: after i became the root user, i opened the file using cat command